# Export From C++ Into Eclipse As Java Program

Tags: java, c++, eclipse, visual-studio-2010

So I have a program that I wrote in C++ (it's a generator) and when you type in some options, it generates a java code in the console, but it can't be copy/pasted and is hard to read (that's just the way windows console is). Is there a way to make that generated java code export into eclipse so that the person can edit it? Even better, could that code be exported to a .jar file?

Comment: How about writing the Java code to a `.java` file instead of the console?

Comment: If it is a command line tool, how about redirecting output of it using  `>` (`java_program_generator.exe -generate_lots_of_code > Result.java` ?

Comment: Matt, how would I do that? Keep in mind, this needs to be a C++ application, it's my project for a class. Sorry if that inconveniences anything.

Comment: FWIW copy/paste does work in Windows console. Here's how: http://superuser.com/questions/170194/i-cant-copy-and-paste-from-a-console-application . (Not that its a good solution to your actual problem.)

Answer (score 1):

You could always redirect the console output to a text file using > pipe:

```
C:\> myapp.exe > output.java
```

Alternatively, here is a tutorial on how to write to file in C++ http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/files/

Update: A short example on how to output the .java file.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

int main () {
  ofstream myfile;
  myfile.open ("Hello.java");
  myfile 
  << "public class Hello {" << endl
  << "  public static void main(String[] args) {" << endl
  << "    System.out.println(\"Hello World\");" << endl
  << "  }" << endl
  << "}";
  myfile.close();
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: The problem is, I have like 25 couts saying what the java code would look like. How do i make it so that it knows what to export into the .java file?

Comment: @JackCook Not sure if I understand correctly. See my updated answer.

Comment: Basically just replace your `cout` with the file output stream.

Answer (score 0):

How about saving the generated code into a *.java file instead of printing it to the cosnole???
to generate a jar file you can either do it on the console using the command "jar" or use eclipse or something to generate the jar

You have to read a bit about c++. Here's how to handle file io
http://www.functionx.com/cpp/articles/filestreaming.htm

cheers